# How to get different UUID each time a test is run in golang?

Tags: go, uuid

I've got an integration test that requires a **different** UUID each time its run but the following code generates the **same** uuid each time.

```
package service

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func TestOne(t *testing.T) {
    id, _ := uuid.NewRandom()
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

Here is similar code in the Go Playground:  https://play.golang.org/p/85yecbn4F80

How do I get this to return a new value with every execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit from June 21 2022**: the scripts do not seem to be cached anymore when using https://go.dev/play/. A new UUID is printed on each run, even when the script remains the same.

---

As users pointed out in the comments, the output in the Go playground is cached. If one tries this on their own command-line, a new UUID is printed on each run.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    id, _ := uuid.NewRandom()
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

And

```bash
$ go run .
604f5ea8-d146-4aac-9a15-4dc33a84eb59
$ go run .
3bc094cf-99c8-4250-98a0-9831fdadedac
$ go run .
b0c13db3-e466-4b5c-a179-e0a16469f11a
```

---

For what it's worth, one can invalidate the Go playground cache by changing the script (e.g., add or modify a comment). This will cause a new UUID to be generated.

Comment: ahh.. and its probably cached in the VS Code's test runner as well.  Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Leaving to the side the reproducibility of the issue using the playground, since your question is specifically about tests, for the sake of completeness, I'm going to add to the existing answer that also the command `go test` caches results — even though it not always does (see below). I don't use VSCode, so I can't tell whether the IDE *itself* does some caching, but consider that if you run a unit test with `uuid.NewRandom()` from the command line, and the test passes, the second time you run it, the printed output will also be the same.

In particular, `go test` caches success results when (quote) "*it's invoked with explicit package arguments*". `./...` and `.` are package arguments.

So if you have:

```
func TestUUID(t *testing.T) {
    u, err := uuid.NewRandom()
    fmt.Println(u)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
}
```

and run `go test -v ./uuidtest/`:

```
=>$ go test -v ./uuidtest/
=== RUN   TestUUID
b1a912ea-0dd2-4ed6-a5af-00ce106b1017
--- PASS: TestUUID (0.00s)
PASS
ok      testproj/uuidtest   0.025s
=>$ go test -v ./uuidtest/
=== RUN   TestUUID
b1a912ea-0dd2-4ed6-a5af-00ce106b1017
--- PASS: TestUUID (0.00s)
PASS
ok      testproj/uuidtest   (cached)
=>$ go test -v ./uuidtest/
=== RUN   TestUUID
b1a912ea-0dd2-4ed6-a5af-00ce106b1017
--- PASS: TestUUID (0.00s)
PASS
ok      testproj/uuidtest   (cached)
```

By the way, the terminal output is nice enough to remind you that the result is indeed `(cached)`.

To avoid the cache on success, you can add the argument `count=1` to the command invocation: `go test -v ./uuidtest/ -count=1`